# File changed event network share

Tags: python, windows, events, python-3.3

**What I want to do:**

I got two directories. Each one contains about 90.000 xml and bak files.

I need the xml files to sync at both folders when a file changes (of course the newer one should be copied).

**The problem is:**

Because of the huge amount of files and the fact that one of the directories is a network share I can't just loop though the directory and compare `os.path.getmtime(file)` values.

Even watchdog and PyQt don't work (tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/detect-file-change-without-polling)).

**The question:**

Is there any other way to get a file changed event (on windows systems) which works for those configuration without looping though all those files?

Comment: I strongly doubt you can get meaningful filesystem notifications from a network share.

Comment: That's the problem why I asked here... If there's no way of doing it on the current config i may switch to ftp and use ftplib to get the time + file

Comment: You could create a service running on both machines that monitor their respective folders; when a file changes, capture thiss event (either use the last example in @Jon-Eric 's link or write a service in C# and use the FIleSystemWatcher component.
When you detect a change, write this change into a file or message queue or database or whatever, and let this be polled by the other machine to get the list of files to be re-synched.
But you'll also need to build some protocol for how your "sync" works when a file has been changed at the same time on both computers :)

Comment: Good idea i may look into that.
And because of the "What will be if both changed the same time" - That's impossible because it's userdata and a user can only be at one of the servers (but may later use the other one, that's why i want to sync the files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the solution:
I changed some of my network share settings and used the [FileSystemWatcher](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html)

To prevent files getting synced on syncing i use a md5 filehash.

The code i use can be found at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Jc8EJ57G) (It's a quick and dirty code and just the parts of it mentioned in the question here).

Answer (score 1):

The code in...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345282/976427

Seems to work for me when passed a network share.

Answer (score 1):

I'm risking giving an answer which is way off here (you didn't specify requirement regarding speed, etc) but... [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) would do exactly that for you for free, and would required writing no code at all.

Of course it might not suit your needs if you required real-time syncing, or if you want to avoid "sharing" your files with a third party (although you can encrypt them first).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the second option on this page?

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Comment: I tried it but it's not returning anything for a network share (at least in my configuration)

Answer (score 0):

From mentioning watchdog, I assume you are running under Linux. For the local machine inotify can help, but for the network share you are out of luck.
Mercurial's inotify extension http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/adding-functionality-with-extensions.html  has the same limitation.

In a similar situation (10K+ files) I have used a cloned mercurial repository with inotify on both the server and the local machine. They automatically commit and notified each other of changes. It had a slight delay (no problem in my case) but as a benifit had a full history
of changes and easily resynced after one of the systems had been down.

Comment: "Is there any other way to get a file changed event (on windows systems) which works for those configuration without looping though all those files?"
Windows Server 2008 so it's not working.
But i found the solution today on my own (i'm adding it as answer, you get the bounty though because your answer is the closest one to my question)

Comment: Sorry, I did not read close enought past the watchdog reference. I once looked at Tim Golden's stuff but I don't work much on Windows. I will have a look at a setup similar to the above which will include Windows clients to see if that would work.